# <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1> in structure

Tags: c++, structure, allocation

Given that I have this function which fills a member of `nicInfo`'s structure:

```
nicList()
{
    std::string num;
    std::string nic_name_command;
    nicInfo* nic = {};
        nic = new nicInfo[nic_numbers];
        for (int i = 0; i < nic_numbers; i++)
        {
            nic_name_command = "ls /sys/class/net | sed -n -s " + std::to_string(i+1) + "p";
            nic[i].name = sshObj->exec_ssh_command(nic_name_command);
        }

    return nic;
}
```

and this is `nicInfo` :

```
struct nicInfo 
{
    const char* name = {};
    const char* ipAddr;
};
```

for example if I have 3 nic cards(nic_numbers = 3), after debugging, nic[4].name is not null or 0. it has this content: `+name  0x1 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1>    const char *`.
 I  want to print names in a while loop like this :

```
int i = 0 ;
while ((nic + i)->name )
    {
        printf("nic name : %s\n", (nic + i)->name);
        i++;
```

but it crashes on i = 4, because it's content is not null. what should I do?
( my function and structure are in c++ but while loop for testing is in c)

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string` in the `nicInfo` structure? If the pointer returned by `sshObj->exec_ssh_command(nic_name_command)` becomes invalid, it will also make that pointer invalid inside the structure (the pointer assignment only copies the *pointer*, not the memory it might point to).

Comment: And if you have three elements in your `nic` array, why do you attempt to use `nic[4]` which would then be out of bounds (as the *fifth* element)?

Comment: because I want to use this output(nicInfo.name) in a c program. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I said that, I want to use a loop to print all members of nic.name, I don't want to print 5th parameter, I want to have a trigger. if there is any better way to print all members I appreciate if you tell me( I can't use number like 4 in this case to define loop's maximum value). @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Instead of allocating an array of your structures, you could use standard containers instead, for example `std::vector<struct nicInfo> myNics;`   The container knows how many objects it contains, and can easily (automatically) change size if you need to add/remove objects.

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
while ((nic + i)->name )
    {
        printf("nic name : %s\n", (nic + i)->name);
        i++;
```

***will*** go out of bounds of the memory you allocated for `nic`. Doing that leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to use a `for` loop to only  iterate over the elements you actually have:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < nic_numbers; ++i)
{
    // ...
}
```

This of course requires that `nic_numbers` use in the loop matches `nic_numbers` used when allocating the memory. If you don't have the size, then you can't use a condition like yours to find the end. You *need* the actual size of the array.

My suggestion is to program *everything* in C++, as then you could use `std::string` and `std::vector<nicInfo>` instead, and that would simplify matters quite a lot.

---

On a side-note: For any pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. For your case that means `(nic + i)->name` is exactly equal to `nic[i].name`. The latter is usually easier to read, and less to write.